# Why the UILabel is not displaying?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uilabel

In my `appDelegate.m` I have this code, but the `UILabel` is not displaying, but only the `UIImageView`.

Why?

```
notificationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(154, 320, 140, 47)];
notificationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notification.png"];

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithString:@"New Videos"];

notificationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(165, 313, 140, 47)]; 
notificationLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
notificationLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
notificationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", numberOfVideos, message];
notificationLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
notificationLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

notificationView.alpha = 0.0;
notificationLabel.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
notificationView.alpha = 1.0;
notificationLabel.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];

[self.window addSubview: notificationView];
[self.notificationView addSubview: notificationLabel];

[UIView commitAnimations];  

[notificationView release];
[notificationLabel release];
```

Comment: is your notificationView(image) is being display

Comment: check your width of imageView and x axis of your label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

notificationLabel is a subview of notificationView. 
It is placed out of bounds of its superview.

Try

```
notificationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
```

and go from there. For all subviews, the top left corner of a super view is (0, 0).

Comment: Now it works fine. Thanks for your CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47) hint!

Answer (score 4):

The width of the notification view is `140`. Your label is being placed at an X location of `165` within the notification view, which is out of the bounds of the notification view. So it isn't visible.

Comment: I have set both the UIImageView and the UILabel at CGRectMake(154, 320, 165, 47), but still no UILabel show.